# LDIF error

Tags: adam

Im having problems applying an ldif file to my Adam instance. I'm receiving an error claiming "Invalid DN Syntax". Ive used the file before and therefore believe the DNs to be acceptable.

Here is an example from the LDIF:-
CN=CA-Certificate,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X

The command used to apply the LDIF:-
ldifde -i -f ENTRUST-adamschema.ldf -s localhost:389 -k -j . -c "CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=X" #schemaNamingContext

any help appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved

the default version of LDIF that runs is different from the one installed with ADAM. If you move the LDIF file to Windows\ADAM then navigate there and run the LDIF command from there then the LDIF is applied without error.

Mark